# Search in array with foreach

Tags: laravel

I am currently pushing with different inputs in my request with a different key each time. Is there a way to search for a key containing "-id" for example?

Here is my request result (with a dd):

[image: request result]

My goal would be to do a

```
foreach($request->contains('id') as $id) {
      //DOING SOME THINGS
}
```

I tried to do this with different PHP functions like `strpos()` or `strpos_recursive()` but either the functions don't exist or it doesn't do the expected result. The goal would also be to be able to retrieve the values associated with the keys.

Comment: why dont you use html input as array?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel provides some nice functions to help you to do this.  First, using `all()` within the standard `request` object, you can see the items coming in through the input.  Then using the Helper function `contains` you can get what you need:

```
public function update(Request $request){
    foreach($request->all() as $key=>$val) {
          if(Str::contains($key, '-id')){
              // etc..
```

Also, the built-in function `has()` may help you without having to loop, as well, if the key is exactly 'id', but I think the above is more what you are looking for:

```
if($request->has('id')){
     $id = $request->input('id');
     // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(array_keys($request) as $r => $val){
    if(strpos($val, 'id')){
        //...
    }
}
```

array_keys function give keys in your array. I received the value of these keys with the foreach loop. I checked if the keys contain id with strpos function. In this way, I reached the desired result.